# Persistence with NamedObjects in Spark Job Server

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-jobserver

Im using the latest SJS version (master) and the application extends SparkHiveJob. In the runJob implementation, I have the following

```
val eDF1 = hive.applySchema(rowRDD1, schema)
```

I would like to persist eDF1 and tried the following

```
    val rdd_topersist = namedObjects.getOrElseCreate("cleanedDF1", {
        NamedDataFrame(eDF1, true, StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY)
       })
```

where the following compile errors occur

```
could not find implicit value for parameter persister: spark.jobserver.NamedObjectPersister[spark.jobserver.NamedDataFrame] 
not enough arguments for method getOrElseCreate: (implicit timeout:scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration, implicit persister:spark.jobserver.NamedObjectPersister[spark.jobserver.NamedDataFrame])spark.jobserver.NamedDataFrame. Unspecified value parameter persister.
```

Obviously this is wrong, but I can't figure what is wrong. I'm fairly new to Scala.

Can someone help me understand this syntax from NamedObjectSupport?

```
def getOrElseCreate[O <: NamedObject](name: String, objGen: => O)
                                    (implicit timeout: FiniteDuration = defaultTimeout,
                                    persister: NamedObjectPersister[O]): O
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should define implicit persister. Looking at the test code, I see something like this

https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver/blob/ea34a8f3e3c90af27aa87a165934d5eb4ea94dee/job-server-extras/test/spark.jobserver/NamedObjectsSpec.scala#L20

Comment: @user1384205 Did the answer help you?